# C# alternative of JavaScript escape() when Cyrillic words are escaped

Tags: c#, t-sql, sql-server-2012, .net-4.5, sqlclr

I have a web application which is sending/inserting data into database table. The values are escaped using the `JavaScript` escape() function. For example:

```
escape('това е текст')
```

converts the text to the following format:

> %u0442%u043E%u0432%u0430%20%u0435%20%u0442%u0435%u043A%u0441%u0442

I want to `unescape` the text and do some manipulation in a `T-SQL` stored procedure.

Note, I am not able to change the way the values are `escaped` and recorded in the database table.

In order to do that I have created several `SQL CLR` funcitons using some build-in `.net` functionality:

- [WebUtility.HtmlDecode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee388354(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [WebUtility.UrlDecode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webutility.urldecode(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [Uri.UnescapeDataString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.unescapedatastring(v=vs.110).aspx)

The issue is that these functions are not being able to decode/unescape the given value because it contains `Cyrillic` characters:

```
SELECT [dbo].[fn_urlDecode] (N'%u0442%u043E%u0432%u0430%20%u0435%20%u0442%u0435%u043A%u0441%u0442')
SELECT [dbo].fn_HtmlDecode (N'%u0442%u043E%u0432%u0430%20%u0435%20%u0442%u0435%u043A%u0441%u0442')
SELECT [dbo].[fn_UnescapeDataString] (N'%u0442%u043E%u0432%u0430%20%u0435%20%u0442%u0435%u043A%u0441%u0442')
```

[image]

Note, that if a use the `SQL CLR` encode/escape and decode/unescape functions everything is working fine:

```
SELECT [dbo].[fn_UrlEncode] (N'това е текст')
SELECT [dbo].[fn_urlDecode] ([dbo].[fn_UrlEncode] (N'това е текст'))
```

[image]

So, I guess the issue is that I am not able to find  `.net` decode/unescape function that can process correctly values transformed by `JavaScript` escape() function.

Could anyone advice how to fix this?

Comment: Have you considered using the snipping tool in Windows so you don't have to abide by those pesky watermarks? =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I was not able to use the `System.Web.dll` I have implemented a regular expression alternative of the `HttpUtility.UrlDecode` function. It is working with both `Unicode` and `ASCII` characters and here is the `C#` definition:

```
/// <summary>
///    Regular expression implementation of the the JavaScript unescape method
/// </summary>
/// <param name="sqlValue">A JavaScript escaped string</param>
/// <returns>Unescaped representation of the input string</returns>
[SqlFunction(DataAccess = DataAccessKind.None, IsDeterministic = true)]
public static SqlString Unescape(SqlString sqlValue)
{
    if (sqlValue.IsNull)
    {
        return new SqlString("");
    }
    else
    {
        string buffer = sqlValue.Value;

        //replacing "Unicode" characters
        buffer = Regex.Replace(buffer, @"%U([0-9A-F]{4})", match => ((char)int.Parse(match.Groups[1].Value, NumberStyles.HexNumber)).ToString(), RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        //replacing "ASCII" character
        buffer = Regex.Replace(buffer, @"%([0-9A-F]{2})", match => ((char)int.Parse(match.Groups[1].Value, NumberStyles.HexNumber)).ToString(), RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

        return new SqlString(buffer);
    }
}
```

For example:

```
SELECT [dbo].[fn_RegexUnescape](N'%u0442%u043E%u0432%u0430%20%u0435%20text%20%14%u20AC');
```

returns:

> това е text €

Answer (score 1):

```
HttpUtility.UrlDecode("%u0442%u043E%u0432%u0430%20%u0435")
```

Works fine for me.

You do need to reference `System.Web`, though.

Comment: I have try to implement this as `SQL CLR` but I am not able to build the `.dll`. I am using `using System.Web;` but getting `The name 'HttpUtility' does not exist in the current context` - so, I try to fix the issue but none of the solution helps as I am not using the client  profile. Could you advice?

Comment: @gotqn Have you referenced the `System.Web.dll` as well?

Comment: Please check this link - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms403279.aspx - `System.Web.dll` is not supported for SQL CLR.

Comment: @gotqn Oh, annoying. Well, http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Web/Util/HttpEncoder.cs,afac0d4e31f5382a copy the code over. It's not *that* long. `WebUtility.UrlDecode` nor `Uri.UnescapeDataString` will not work, since simple unicode characters are not supposed to be encoded; `HttpUtility.UrlDecode` is specifiacally designed for compatibility with javascript's `encode` (which *shouldn't* be encoding cyrillic, but is).

Comment: In order to use the code I need to import other not supported libraries. Generally, I have an option to register in SQL Server unsupported library, but it seems to risky for me, as it is not tested by the `MS SQL` team and might stop working in the future.

Comment: @gotqn The other methods that are called also aren't all too complicated. Granted, it's a bit more work, but not that much. It's still just something like 200-300 lines of code.